GitHub Actions: Is $GITHUB_SHA stable for the life of a complex workflow?
I have a workflow with multiple jobs and jobs that use: another workflow via a workflow_call. The workflows are all in the same repo that is being checked out.
If the underlying ref is modified during this workflow, will the actions/checkout in all jobs see the same head commit?
In actions checkout I can see this code:
  result.ref = core.getInput('ref')
  if (!result.ref) {
    if (isWorkflowRepository) {
      result.ref = github.context.ref
      result.commit = github.context.sha

      // Some events have an unqualifed ref. For example when a PR is merged (pull_request closed event),
      // the ref is unqualifed like "main" instead of "refs/heads/main".
      if (result.commit && result.ref && !result.ref.startsWith('refs/')) {
        result.ref = `refs/heads/${result.ref}`
      }
    }
  }

And other source in the repo will use +${commit}:... as the refspec if result.commit is set, so I know that if the commit is set, then it will be used by checkout by default.
My question then is about github.context.sha - is that stable between the jobs and workflow_calls? The source for that value is:
this.sha = process.env.GITHUB_SHA as string
But I'm not sure how to track further than that.
Is $GITHUB_SHA guaranteed to be stable, specifically for push and workflow_dispatch events, for the life of the workflow? If so, it makes my life a lot simpler. For push events, there is a head_commit in the event payload so I feel like that would be stable. For workflow_dispatch events there is no such field in the payload, so I'm uncertain when or how often GITHUB_SHA is re-evaluated. Once per workflow? Once per job?
What happens when you re-run jobs? Woudl GITHUB_SHA change?
Cross-post from https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/136513 where I asked the same question.

I found this which says:

Re-running a workflow or jobs in a workflow uses the same GITHUB_SHA (commit SHA) and GITHUB_REF

Stands to reason that if it is stable over re-runs, it'll be stable for the life of the workflow?
